# Proving that $\sup_{B_R} |u| \leq \frac{R^2}{2n} \sup_{B_R} |f|$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

I have a question that I'm getting stuck on. I am given $R>0$, and $c,f\in C(\overline{B_R})$, where $c \leq 0$ on $\overline{B_R}$ and assume that $u \in C^2(B_R) \cap C( \overline{B_R})$ satisfies
$$  \begin{cases} \Delta u + cu = f & x \in B_R \\ u = 0 & on\,\,\, \partial B_R \end{cases} $$
Prove that
$$ \sup_{B_R} |u| \leq \frac{R^2}{2n} \sup_{B_R} |f| \,\,. $$
Hint: let $A =\sup_{B_R} |f|$ and define $v(x)= \frac{A}{2n} (R^2 - |x|^2)$ and prove that $|u(x) \leq v(x)$ on $B_R$.

I'm thinking I need to use a maximum principle type argument to show this result, but I'm getting stuck on how to start this.

Comment: Did you prove that $|u| \le v$?

Comment: @ArcticChar  I haven't been able to show that, yet.

Comment: That part uses the weak maximum principle. See what happens at the maximum of $u-v$.

Comment: @ArcticChar Got it. Showed that $-v \le u \le v$ and was able to show the result from that.